# Best way to implement a stored procedure with full text search

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, full-text-search, dynamic-sql

I would like to run a search with MSSQL Full text engine where given the following user input:
"Hollywood square"

I want the results to have both Hollywood and square[s] in them.

I can create a method on the web server (C#, ASP.NET) to dynamically produce a sql statement like this:

```
SELECT TITLE
FROM MOVIES
WHERE CONTAINS(TITLE,'"hollywood*"')
AND CONTAINS(TITLE, '"square*"')
```

Easy enough.  HOWEVER, I would like this in a stored procedure for added speed benefit and security for adding parameters.

Can I have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: Dynamic SQL like that will probably not produce a speed benefit in a stored procedure.  Stored procedures are great when the execution plan remains the same, but you're designing one that will change - that will incur sp recompiles.

Comment: I asked in the hopes that there was some small, not so well documented way to do it.
Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agreed with above, look into AND clauses

```
SELECT TITLE
FROM MOVIES
WHERE CONTAINS(TITLE,'"hollywood*" AND "square*"')
```

However you shouldn't have to split the input sentences, you can use variable

```
SELECT TITLE
FROM MOVIES
WHERE CONTAINS(TITLE,@parameter)
```

by the way
search for the exact term (contains)
search for any term in the phrase (freetext)

Comment: I used GoogleFTS (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Full-Text+Search+(2008)/64248/) [you may need to sign up].  It takes your search terms and formats the '@parameter' to behave like google, but using SQL server T-SQL commands.
Thanks to everyone for their time.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I had to do this (with MSSQL Server 2005) I ended up moving the whole search functionality over to Lucene (the Java version, though Lucene.Net now exists I believe). I had high hopes of the full text search but this specific problem annoyed me so much I gave up.

Comment: I went with Google FTS because the google search language is so ubiquitous, it just seemed natural.  The speed isn't too bad either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the AND logical operator in your string? I pass in a raw string to my sproc and stuff 'AND' between the words.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx